# Revising a Ruby method to represent integer partition as ordered string (without flattening?)

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, formatting

I'm writing for help to improve the Ruby method below to convert an integer partition represented as an array of n integers (11 = [5,1,5]), where the order of the partitions matter, to string consisting of 1s and 0s, where the 1s represent units (or tick marks) and 0s represent arithmetic separators (+). The final string returned is not meant to be read as a number in any positional base system, though it could be.

For example, I want to convert the integer 11 represented by the array 11=[5,1,5] to "1111101011111" which represents, 11=(11111)(+)(1)(+)(11111) or 11. Since order matters, 11=[5,5,1] represents a different partition, namely "1111101111101".

As in the examples, the arrays of integers passed to this method are not sorted, so method should return the representation using the delimiters in the order of parts as given.

In the method below, I've built up the representation from the given partition array using another temporary array and then made use of flatten in the return, and am wondering how I might have handled this better with Ruby.

Here's what I've tried. I'd appreciate some help improving this code. In particular I'm hoping for feedback on how I'm flattening the final array and learning maybe how I could possibly avoid using the joins and build the string directly without resorting to the temporary array.

```
def partition_to_string(n)
  representation = []
  n.each_with_index do |partition,index|
    if index == n.size - 1 then
      representation << [Array.new(partition,"1")]
    else 
      representation << [Array.new(partition,"1"),"0"]
    end
  end
  return representation.flatten.join
end

puts partition_to_string([11])
#=> "11111111111"
puts partition_to_string([5,1,5])
#=> "1111101011111"
puts partition_to_string([5,5,1])
#=> "1111101111101"
```

For a trivial partition of a number into 1 part, that is a string consisting of just 1's (for example, 11 = [11]) the string doesn't require any zeros, since it consists of only 1 part, so I want to represent it as simply [11] = "111111111111" (11 1's). Likewise, in a partitions of multiple parts, for the final summand, there is no need to append an additional 0 at the very end. That is, the method should return for [5,1,5] = "1111101011111" rather than "11111010111110." I think I handled these cases in the code above looping through the array and checking current element with the size of the initial array passed.

Comment: It becomes easier when done in two steps: 1) converting `[5, 1, 5]` to `["11111", "1", "11111"]` and 2) joining the latter using `"0"` as a separator.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
ary.map { |n| "1" * n }.join("0")
```

So `[5,1,5].map { |n| "1" * n }.join("0") #=> "1111101011111"`

Considering that `["1"].join("0") #=> "1"`

Comment: This is exactly the easy Ruby answer I was searching for. Thanks, iGian for your quick answer.